# Dualband WiFi adapters/routers

Tags: wireless-networking, dual-band, 802.11

I seem to remember reading somewhere about dualband adapters that can take advantage of specifically-configured dualband routers in order to connect on both the 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands simultaneously, thus (theoretically) doubling the maximum throughput.

At the moment, I cannot find anything about this, or the article I saw before.

Is this possible? If so, what are some adapters/routers that support this?

**EDIT**

I found a router that claims to support this: [http://www.amazon.com/Netgear-Wireless-Gigabit-Router-WNDR3700/dp/B002HWRJY4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HWRJY4)

It says "Simultaneous operation on 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz frequencies for combined 600 Mbps speed." How exactly does this work, and what is the name for this technology? MIMO does not seem to exactly fit the bill, as MIMO does not require two different frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you I *think* you're thinking of two different things to do with the wireless N standard - MIMO or Multi in Multi out as well as 802.11n running on the 5ghz frequency as well as the 2.4 ghz frequency.

[MIMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO) uses multiple antennae at both the ends of a connection to do things like split up the connection. Any router with MIMO should be able to do this in conjunction with a decent wireless N adaptor

The 5ghz frequency is less used, so there's less signal contention than 2.4 ghz.However, cheaper N  devices only support 2.4, both when it comes to routers and wireless adaptors it seems.

Comment: Surprisingly (and sadly) many devices today STILL don't support 5Ghz wireless-n, even the non-cheap ones. One glaring example is the iPhone (all versions including 4 and 4S).

Comment: I have updated my question with a link and more specific question.